# what is ddns-update-style in isc-dhcp-server on ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, dhcp

I have a ubuntu server setup as a router (among other things), I now am adding a dhcp server to it. When configuring isc-dhcp-server, the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file has an option called `ddns-update-style`, which can be set to `ad-hoc`, `interim`, `standard`, `none`. I have two nics (`em1`,`em2`). `em1` is set to dhcp for my isp which gives me my public ip address. `em2` on the other hand is my internal interface for the dhcp server with a static ip of `10.0.0.1`. Now I've been setting the DNS on the clients manually, with my ISPs two dns addresses. What would ddns-update-style do? I would imagine you either set it to `standard` or `none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option has nothing to do with DNS servers. To push DNS server addresses to clients, you have to specify them as a DHCP 'option':

```
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

---

Meanwhile, "DDNS" is the No-IP style "dynamic DNS", where the DHCP server automatically adds clients to your DNS domain, and `ddns-update-style` selects the method used by dhcpd to submit updates to the DNS server.

See `man dhcpd.conf`, sections "Dynamic DNS updates" and "The DNS update scheme" for differences between `standard` and `interim`. (Basically, `interim` uses the old draft protocol.)